# Why conduction of charge occurs?

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

Consider a  positively charged conductor touched with a metal wire. We know that charge from the conductor will flow to the wire (assuming that the wire is at a lower potential). The cause of this charge flow that I can think of is that the charged body was experiencing a net outward pressure of $\sigma^2/2$, where $\sigma$ is the local surface charge density, this now added with the fact that charge has a place to flow (the wire) causes conduction. Is this view correct?

PS: I am working in the HL system instead of SI which for our purposes means that $\epsilon_0=1$

Comment: pressure has not the physical dimension of a charge density squared

Comment: @basics yes indeed in the SI system, but here I am working in HL, I'll edit it.

Comment: You don't say whether the charges in the "charged object" are mobile. If they are not, then charge does not flow from the object into the wire. You also don't say whether the charge on the object is positive or negative, so we don't know if it will flow toward or away from the wire (supposed to be initially at a lower potential than the object).

Comment: @ThePhoton I have edited the post to correct the ambiguities, thanks for pointing those out.